# How do I get multiple pdfs of different sizes using dompdf

Tags: php, html, laravel, dompdf, laravel-dompdf

I have a single php file. I want to convert the html codes in the php page to pdf with dompdf.

My PHP page is like this;

```
<!--First Page-->
<div class="container">
    
    Page 1
</div>
<div class="page-break></div>

<!--Second Page-->
<div class="container">
    
    Page 2
</div>
<div class="page-break></div>

<!--Third Page-->
<div class="container">
    
    Page 3
</div>
<div class="page-break></div>

....

<!--Sixth Page-->
<div class="container">
    
    Page 6
</div>
```

I want to convert this php page as pdf as shown below.

page size landscape,
page size landscape,
page size landscape,
page size portrait,
page size portrait,
page size portrait

Can you help?

I can convert my html codes in the php page to pdf file using dompdf. However, I cannot make the html pages in my php page horizontal and vertical.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you need to provide updates. Stackoverflow isn't a forum. The question and answer areas are distinct, separate, and clearly labelled. Please take the [tour] if you're unsure how the site works. Thanks.